# Magento base URL incorrect

Tags: magento

My Magento installation is multi domain multi site setup.

I have been scratching my head on the problem of wrong base URL for atleast 3 days now.

extinguisher.atozstores.com is the site with this problem.

Here, the search URL is set whiteboard.atozstores.com. I have checked and confirmed it in phpMyAdmin that both the secure and unsecure URL is extinguisher.atozstores.com.

whiteboard.atozstores.com is the base site for this sub site.

[image]

Any pointers on where the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places in core_config_data where you have to change URLs for Magento multi-store setup. 
Please, run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `value` LIKE '%http%'
```

There you will see all the places where you have to verify the URLs.